# Derivation of normal equations for maximum likelihood and least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, least-squares, maximum-likelihood

The question stems from the text Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Bishop, Chapter 3.1.1. To say my maths is rusty is an understatement so I would appreciate any nudge in the right direction regarding the below.

The logarithm of the likelihood functions of a standard univariate Gaussian is given below:

$$(1)\quad \frac{N}{2} \ln \beta - \frac{N}{2}\ln 2 \pi - \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N\{t_n - \mathbf w^T \mathbf \phi(\mathbf x_n) \}^2$$

Taking the gradient(derivative) with respect to $\mathbf w$ and setting this equal to zero we get:

$$(2)\quad0 = \sum_{n=1}^N\{t_n - \mathbf w^T \mathbf \phi(\mathbf x_n) \}\phi(\mathbf x_n)^T $$

$$(3)\quad0 = \sum_{n=1}^Nt_n \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T - \mathbf w^T(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf \phi(\mathbf x_n) \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T)$$

Solving for $\mathbf w$ we get:

$$(4)\quad\mathbf w_{ML}=(\mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf \Phi)^{-1} \mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf {\mathtt t}$$

where

$$(5)\quad\mathbf \Phi = \phi_j(\mathbf x_n)$$

Now for the questions.

(a) In (2) when using the chain rule why do we get $\phi(\mathbf x_n)^T$ instead of $\phi(\mathbf x_n)?$

(b) Is the following valid to get from (3) to (4)? Continuing from (3)

$$\mathbf w^T(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf \phi(\mathbf x_n) \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T) = \sum_{n=1}^Nt_n \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T$$

$$[\mathbf w^T(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf \phi(\mathbf x_n) \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T)]^T = [\sum_{n=1}^Nt_n \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T]^T$$

$$\mathbf w_{ML}(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf \phi(\mathbf x_n) \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T) = \sum_{n=1}^N \phi(\mathbf x_n) t_n $$

Where $\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf \phi(\mathbf x_n) \phi(\mathbf x_n)^T$ = $(\mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf \Phi)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \phi(\mathbf x_n) t_n = \mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf {\mathtt t}$

$$\mathbf w_{ML}(\mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf \Phi)(\mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf \Phi)^{-1}=(\mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf \Phi)^{-1} \mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf {\mathtt t}$$

$$(4)\quad\mathbf w_{ML}=(\mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf \Phi)^{-1} \mathbf \Phi^T \mathbf {\mathtt t}$$

If it is not valid can you please point out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) no reason, really. Expressing the gradient as a row vector sets up for what is done in step 3, but you could also have is proportional to $\phi(x_n)$ and then write $(t_n-w^T\phi(x_n))^2 = (t_n-\phi(x_n)^Tw)^2$ and then multiply this scalar by the column vector $\phi(x_n)$ on the left.

(b) Yes, but in the third line $w_{ML}$ should be on the right of $\Phi^T\Phi.$ Also you should probably be explicit about which index is which here. $\Phi = \phi_j(x_n)$ seems to suggest the second index is $n$ but what you really have in this notation is $\Phi_{nj} = \phi_j(x_n).$

Answer (score 0):

(a) Chris Bishop's presentation is dual to the one in [Bierman's *Factorization Methods for Discrete Sequential Estimation*."](http://a.co/hWXXYZH). In Bishop's, the weights — uknown quantities to be estimated — are in an $M$‑dimensional column vector and the values of the basis functions — the *modeling* functions that purport to match the data within some error — are also assembled in $M$‑dimensional column vectors, $N$ of them, one $M$‑dimensional value for each input datum $\boldsymbol{x}_{n\in[1..N]}$. The components of the evaluated modeling functions are assembled in Bishop's *design matrix*

$$\left(\boldsymbol{\Phi}_{N\times{M}}\right)_{nj}=\phi_{j\in[1..M]}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{n\in[1..N]}\right)=\phi\left(\boldsymbol{x}_n\right)\,\phi\left(\boldsymbol{x}_n\right)^\intercal$$

@spaceisdarkgreen above correctly clarified the indices: Bishop tacitly rotates his $N$ column vectors $\phi\left(\boldsymbol{x}_n\right)$ into rows to assemble $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$. Because of these choices, Bishop must write $\mathbf{t}=\boldsymbol{w}^\intercal\boldsymbol{\Phi}^\intercal$  to get all the "label" data $\mathbf{t}=\left(\boldsymbol{t}_1,\boldsymbol{t}_2,\ldots,\boldsymbol{t}_N,\right)^\intercal$ because he tacitly transposed each $\phi\left(\boldsymbol{x}_n\right)$ to build $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ and must transpose $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ again to use it.

Bierman, on the other hand, de-emphasizes the modeling functions and just calls their $N$ values "observation partials," each of dimension $M$. This means *partial derivatives of each of the $N$ predicted labels with respect to the $M$ unknown parameters* $\boldsymbol{w}$. As partial derivatives of $\boldsymbol{w}$, they are already row-vectors, and don't need transposing (in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54355/the-gradient-as-a-row-vs-column-vector), we can see Bierman's partials as values of covector differential forms in the $M$‑dimensional cotangent space of the outputs of the modeling functions; see [Hubbard and Hubbard](http://matrixeditions.com/5thUnifiedApproach.html) for differential forms).

Assembling these $N$ values of the $M$‑dimensional partials as rows is natural in this treatment, no transposes required. Bierman denotes the design matrix as $A$ and multiplies it on the left of the column vector $\boldsymbol{w}$ of parameters-to-estimate. Bierman writes $A\,{\boldsymbol{w}}$ in place of Bishop's

$$\boldsymbol{w}^\intercal\phi\left(\boldsymbol{x}_n\right)\,\phi\left(\boldsymbol{x}_n^\intercal\right)=\boldsymbol{w}^\intercal_{1\times{M}}\,\boldsymbol{\Phi}^\intercal_{M\times{N}}$$

Because of the transposes, Bishop's $\boldsymbol{w}^\intercal\,\boldsymbol{\Phi}^\intercal$ is dual to Bierman's $A\,\boldsymbol{w}$.

I'm a physicist, so I find Bierman's notion of observation partials intuitive. Partials are 1‑forms and thus covectors (row vectors); every physicist drills this *ad nauseum*. I also find Bierman's notation through his whole book less cumbersome than Bishop's; that's a mere matter of taste. So far as I can tell, the two treatments produce the same answers, at least after we figure out how Bishop's $\alpha$ and $\beta$ relate to Bierman's *a-priori covariances* in his ultimate destination: Kalman filtering. That's a non-trivial task I won't address here.

The duality might have a philosophical edge. Bishop comes at linear regression from the viewpoint of approximating arbitrary functions as linear combinations of a finite number $M$ of basis functions, and he is explicit about the generality of the basis functions through his $\phi$ notation. Bishop is *functions first, weights second*, if you will. Bierman comes at the same problem from the standpoint of fitting data via recursive filters like Kalman's and is preoccupied with various factorizations of the design-or-partials matrix for performance (memory and time) and numerical stability, e.g., SVD and Cholesky. Bierman's recursive filters process the $A$ matrix one row (one gradient) at a time, and so execute in constant, $O(M)$ memory at the outset (see [Beckman's self-publshed papers on Kalman Folding](http://vixra.org/author/brian_beckman) [disclaimer; I wrote them]). Bierman is *weights first, functions second* if you will. He is less concerned with the source of the partials, be they through evaluating basis functions or through deeper approximation schemes, which are a cottage industry in Kalman filtering (see [Zarchan and Musoff](http://a.co/efMWS7x) and [Yaacov Bar-Shalom](http://a.co/03fJx8i)).

(b) I concur with the answer above.